# Is there a way to compress DICOM data?

Tags: image-processing, dicom

Say, I have a sequence on `.dicom` files in a folder. The cumulative size is about 100 Mb. It's a lot of data. I tried to convert data into `.nrrd` and `.nii`, but those files had the summary size of the converted `.dicom` files (which is fairly predictable, though `.nrrd` was compressed with `gzip`). I'd like to know, if there a file format that would give me far less sizes, or just a way to solve that. Perhaps, `.vtk`, or something else (not sure it qould work). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strictly interpreted `100mb` means, to those familiar with the relevant standards, `one hundred millibits` which is not a lot of data by anyone's standards.  If you actually mean `one hundred megabits` or even `one hundredmegabytes` a lot of us will still think `hmm, actually not so much data`.  Finally, here's a reference which might actually help http://www.mccauslandcenter.sc.edu/mricro/dicom/index.html

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark That wasn't helpful, but thanks for mentioning, I edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DICOM supports compression of the pixel data within the file itself. The idea of DICOM is that it's format agnostic from the point of view of the pixel data it holds.

DICOM can hold raw pixel data and also can hold JPEG-compressed pixel data, as well as many other formats. The transfer syntax tag of the DICOM file gives you the compression protocol of the pixel data within the DICOM.

The first thing is to figure out whether you need lossless or lossy compression. If lossy, there are a lot of options, and the compression ratio is quite high in some - the tradeoff is that you do lose fidelity and the images may not be adequate for diagnostic purposes. There are also lossless compression schemes - like JPEG2000, RLE and even JPEG-LS. These will compress the pixel data, but retain diagnostic quality without any image degradation.

You can also zip the files, which, if raw, should produce very good results. What are you looking to do w/ these compressed DICOMs?

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I was going to use files in a web app, but decided to use this data partly.

Comment: if you're using them for a web app, you might just want to extract the image data from the DICOMs and save that data as JPEGs. DCMTK toolkit (http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en) has very good support for extracting image data from DICOM into JPEG (there is even a command-line utility to do this).

Comment: Hah, well, I'd be glad to, but it's a 3D visualization :)

Comment: ah. you'll need to generate a mesh then. I believe you can use the pixelmed (http://www.pixelmed.com) library to help you in that.